# On concavity using the third derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, solution-verification

(1) If $f''(a) = f''(x_0) = f''(b) = 0$ where $a < x_0 < b$, $f'''(x_0) > 0$ and $a$, $x_0$ and $b$ are the only inflection points of $f$ in the interval $[a, b]$, then $f$ is concave down on $(a, x_0)$ and concave up on $(x_0, b)$.

(2) If $f''(a) = f''(x_0) = f''(b) = 0$ where $a < x_0 < b$, $f'''(x_0) < 0$ and $a$, $x_0$ and $b$ are the only inflection points of $f$ in the interval $[a, b]$, then $f$ is concave up on $(a, x_0)$ and concave down on $(x_0, b)$.

Can someone please confirm that these always hold?

Proof:

Let $a < x_0 < b$, $f'''(x_0) > 0$ and $f''(a) = f''(x_0) = f''(b) = 0$ and $a$, $x_0$ and $b $ the only inflection points of $f$ in the interval $[a, b]$.

If $f'''(x_0) > 0$, that means that there exists a $\epsilon$ so that $f''(x_0 + \epsilon) > f''(x_0) > f''(x_0 - \epsilon)$. Since $f''(x_0) = 0$ and $a$, $x_0$ and $b$ are the only inflection points of $f$, between $a$ and $x_0$ and between $x_0$ and $b$, $f''$ is either negative or positive, we have $f''(x_0 + \epsilon) > 0 > f''(x_0 - \epsilon)$ and since $(x_0 - \epsilon) \in (a, x_0)$, $f''$ is negative on $(a, x_0)$. Since $f''(x_0 + \epsilon) > 0$ and $(x_0 + \epsilon) \in (x_0, b)$, $f''$ is positive on $(x_0, b)$. Thus, $f$ is concave down on $(a, x_0)$ and concave up on $(x_0, b)$. Similarly, for $f'''(x_0) < 0$, $f$ is concave up on $(a, x_0)$ and concave down on $(x_0, b)$.

Is everything fine with that?

On the interval $[a, b]$, there could also be a $c$ so that $f''(c) = 0$ but $c$ is not an inflection point. But since that doesn't change the concavity and only adds one point to $f''$ that is $0$, we can still say that $f$ is concave up or down on an interval containing $c$ by the definition of monotony of $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the result is correct but your proof does not make complete sense.

First, you rightly state there exists and $\epsilon_0$ such that ..., but later on you incorrectly use the universal quantification.

Based on your proof, all you can say is, there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $f$ is concave down (respectively up) on $(x-\epsilon, x)$ and concave up (respectively, down) on $(x, x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Since $a$, $x_0$ and $b$ are the only inflection points on the interval $[a, b]$, $f''$ on $(a, x_0)$ and on $(x_0, b)$ has to either be positive or negative. So having $f''(x_0 + \epsilon) > 0$ and $f''(x_0 - \epsilon) < 0$  means that $f''$ is negative on $(a, x_0)$ and $f''(x_0 + \epsilon) > 0$  means that $f''$ is positive on $(x_0, b)$, doesn't it?